# Failure delivering result ResultInfo{request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }}

Tags: android, flutter, permissions

I am trying to get READ_CONTACTS,WRITE_CONTACTS permission.
Whenever I build the app first time it asks me permissions, when I allow it , the app closes suddenly.
Here is my code

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _askPermissions('');
  }
  

  Future<void> _askPermissions(String routeName) async {
    PermissionStatus permission = await Permission.contacts.status;
    if (permission == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      getContacts();
    } else {
      _handleInvalidPermissions(permission);
    }
  }

  void _handleInvalidPermissions(PermissionStatus permissionStatus) {
    if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Access denied'));
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    } else if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
      final snackBar =
      SnackBar(content: Text('Data not available on device'));
    }
  }
```

This is the error message that I get in my Android Monitor

```
Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime( 4831): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 4831): Process: com.sakhi.dailler, PID: 4831
E/AndroidRuntime( 4831): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.sakhi.dailler/com.sakhi.dailler.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 4831):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4386)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4831):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4428)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4831):    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4831):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4831):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4831):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1814)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4831):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4831):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:280)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4831):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6710)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4831):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4831):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4831):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4831): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 4831):    at com.yanisalfian.flutterphonedirectcaller.FlutterPhoneDirectCallerHandler.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterPhoneDirectCallerPlugin.kt:85)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4831):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry$FlutterEngineActivityPluginBinding.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.java:785)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4831):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.java:413)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4831):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:816)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4831):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterActivity.java:952)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4831):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:7608)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4831):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7458)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4831):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4379)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4831):    ... 11 more
I/Process ( 4831): Sending signal. PID: 4831 SIG: 9
```

I already defined permission as direct child of manifest element in AndoridManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

Why permission dialog box is not showing up?

Why I am getting empty permissions and grantResults array in call back method?